# Akamai Cache rest url based on the query string pattern

Tags: akamai

We have a rest request going to an external server and getting the response back.
This is exposed over the internet.

--https://resst.xyzs.com/api/remote/app/tax/task/lookup?placeName=urban&age=17&state=MD&atg-rest-http-method=get

How can i cache them in Akamai,I want to cache them based on the query parameter , so Only the first time request with the same goes to backend server and subsequent one's are served from Akamai cache.
in this eg : placeName=urban&age=17&state=MD

Please share your thoughts on this,

Warm Regards
Anilal

trying to make it work with caching, so only one request goes to the actuall server, rest all will be served from akamai cache.

Our backend data is not volatile, it is kind of constant most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with simple path condition (probably wildcard) and caching behavior (Edge TTL and Downstream TTL) . You need Akamai contract subscription for caching.  Query string parameters are covered automatically.

[https://techdocs.akamai.com/api-definitions/docs/caching#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20%E2%80%8BAkamai%E2%80%8B,cache%2Dbusting%20headers%20to%20clients](https://techdocs.akamai.com/api-definitions/docs/caching#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20%E2%80%8BAkamai%E2%80%8B,cache%2Dbusting%20headers%20to%20clients).